# Website character encoding

Tags: character-encoding, special-characters

I have a website in Turkish language. I have the text in turkish and shows well in the editor. When i publish it and view it in the browser;

the term : müdürlügü

shows as :  m�d�rl�g�

How can i avoid this?

Character encoding of the site is : UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your webpage, set character encoding to UTF-8:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Did you save the file as UTF-8? Is the server serving up the page as UTF-8? Can you provide an URL for us to check? Thanks.

Comment: :) That was the trick. I wasnt saving the file as UTF-8. Now works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

HTML entities: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm

Your character for instance, can be found here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00fc/index.htm

Comment: there are so many text like this. i cant go one by one to change them. it s not efficient. there are other sites which displays just fine.